# Making the postgreSQL script configurable

Tags: sql, postgresql, shell, config

I have created a sql script to delete a table from a database in which the records is older than 7 days with below schema.

**delete.sql**

```
DELETE from abc where eventtime::date <=(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-INTERVAL '7 DAYS')::date;
COMMIT;
```

I am executing the above sql script using my shell script as below:

**xyz.sh**

```
sudo  -u user psql --d db --file=<<path>>/delete.sql
```

Now, i have to make this script configurable i.e. user can change the duration which can be read by script directly rather than changing the script always. So, i am trying to create some **.config file** and to use it as a reference in sql script. But i am unable to do it. Any help with how i can pass the variable from .config file to postgreSQL script file.

**Expected scenario:**

**.config file**

```
# duration to delete the records from the database
DURATION =7 DAY
```

**delete.sql**

```
DELETE from abc where eventtime::date <=(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-INTERVAL '$DURATION')::date;
COMMIT;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I really don't understand this use case. How is the user going to execute this script? What OS? If you're using `psql`, you can use a bash script or bat file to prompt user for duration and then run your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: postgres has built in support for parameters in scripts (the `-v` flag). See the answer from op below.

In **xyz.sh**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

. ./.config

sudo -u user psql -d db -c "DELETE FROM abc WHERE eventtime::DATE <=(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '${DURATION} days')::DATE"
```

You'd have to quote the duration in your *.config* file because there's a space in it:

```
# Interval in the past to keep
DURATION="7 DAY"
```

If you want to keep the script in a separate file you'll have to do token replacement on it before feeding it to `psql`. A utility like `sed` can be used:

In **xyz.sh**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

. ./.config

cat delete.sql | sed -e "s/DURATION/${DURATION}/g" | sudo -u user psql -d db
```

Comment: I have updated the query. I have added my shell script from where my sql script is being called.

Comment: Is there an objection to including the SQL in the bash script? If you include it inline you will be able to template it as above. It will be more work to read it from a separate file.

Comment: yes i was able to achieve from the shell script giving it inline but i was looking for someway to configure sql script.

Comment: You could use `sed` to do token replacement. I've updated the example.

Comment: thanks. i tried and it works perfectly fine. Can you please provide the explanation of the command "cat delete.sql | sed -e "s/DURATION/${DURATION}/g" | sudo -u user psql -d db". Thanks a lot.

Comment: sed is being used here to replace the word **DURATION** with the value from the config file. The actual sed command being executed is `s/DURATION/7 DAY/g` - bash does the variable substitution in the command before executing it. In the land of sed `s` means substitute and `g` means global (every occurrence).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to try one more way which does not involve sed command

**.config file**

```
# Interval in the past to keep
DURATION='7 DAYS'
```

**xyz.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

source /<<path>>/file.config

sudo -u user psql -d db -f delete.sql -v DURATION="'${DURATION}'"
```

> "'${DURATION}'" returns the output as '7 DAYS'

**delete.sql**

```
DELETE from abc where eventtime::date <=(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-INTERVAL :DURATION)::date;
COMMIT;
```

So, now when you execute the **xyz.sh** file it will met the expected scenario.